# Accurately rotate plan to snap to another

Tags: snapping

I'm trying to get to grips with Blender for arch vis, having usually used CAD software. The snapping is particularly illogical and seems overly complex.

I have two plan drawings which I'd like to align, so I need to rotate one accurately to meet the other. What combination of Pivot Points and Snap settings do I need? I feel like I've tried everything.

Currently have the plans aligned at one point (highlighted bottom right).

Thanks
[image: Misaligned plans]

Comment: I imagine you try already *Transform Pivot Point* to *3D Cursor* and *Snap To* to *Vertex*, perhaps with *Align Rotation to Target* checked ?

Comment: Yep, that doesn't seem to do it. It's snapping, but doesn't seem to let me pick a 'from' point for the rotation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the new Snap Base functionality in Blender 4.0. You just need to hit  <kbd>B</kbd>  while in some transform operation( <kbd>G</kbd> ,  <kbd>R</kbd> ,  <kbd>S</kbd> )(See status bar hints while in transform operation), click on point you want to snap an then the point you want to snap to. You will need a Transform Pivot adequate for your situation and this is where it gets slightly less convenient than in some CAD software where you define it during operation, but it's not extremely inconvenient and you can just use 3d Cursor snapped to a vertex. You can use snap menu( <kbd>Shift</kbd>  +  <kbd>G</kbd> ) to snap 3d cursor to selection in edit mode.

[image]

You need 3d Cursor selected as Transform Pivot Point in the header of 3d viewport and also you must hit  <kbd>B</kbd>  before you specify axis by hitting  <kbd>Z</kbd>  in this case.

[image]

You can also snap 3d Cursor to something in different ways, for example while dragging it  <kbd>Shift</kbd>   +   <kbd>RMB</kbd>  you can also hold  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>  for temporary snapping mode, but you have to have Snap to Vertex enabled in the snapping menu in the header of the 3d Viewport to snap it to vertices.

As for snapping functionality being overly complex and illogical... Well, having to use CAD software myself, I get where this comes from since in some cases it might feel easier in CAD software, but don't forget that Blender is mostly for 3d work and sometimes that complexity might be very useful. Once you get used to the complex snapping functionality in Blender you might come to like it - it is very flexible and very full of functionality. It's hard to deny it being quite complex though.

Comment: Thank you, that's done it! Frustrating that I couldn't achieve it in Blender 3 but at least we're there. Much appreciated.

Comment: It's possible in Blender 3 or even 2, but this base thing is way more convenient.

Answer (score 0):

*(Using Blender 3.6.8)*

- *Transform Pivot Point* set to *3D Cursor*.
- *Snap To* set to *Vertex*, *Align Rotation to Target* checked, *Affect* set to *Move* and *Rotate*.

[image: Animation]

Comment: Thanks, but I copied your settings exactly but it stayed in the same position - almost like rotations were locked to increments of 10 degrees and therefore the change wasn't big enough to register.