CAD like snap base point for moving object
I am new to blender but have some experience on Autocad or CorelDraw.
I simply want to move an object. But not from the center of the object, but from some point on the edges of an object, e.g. one corner of a cube.
I am used from other tools to start move and then get asked "start point", where I can select some standard points of an object like "endpoint", "middle point" or simply interception point of two lines, and after that, define the "target point".
I wasn't able to find the way to do this with blender and would apreciate some help.

hello could you please show an illustration of what you want?

https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/314440/accurately-rotate-plan-to-snap-to-another

@moonboots I don't know how I could illustrate my question. I would like to snap to the corner of a cube and move it to 0,0,0, the corner, not the center of the cube!


Make sure snapping is on in the header (magnet icon) and make sure vertex or other geometry element is chosen as snap target
Set a selection up
Start some transformation (like Move with G or Rotate with R)
While the transformation is ongoing, but before confirming, press B to set a base point
Click the desired based point with the aid of the snap indicators
Complete the operation by clicking the target placement.


Optionally, to get a midpoint between two points whenever snapping, press the A key to start the Add Snap Point mode, then hover over every vertex you want to average over and press press A to include them in the averaging point.
So if you want to have your base point as middle of a certain edge, after pressing B to get a base point, press A to start Add Snap Point operation, with the mouse cursor hover vertex 1 and press A, hover over vertex 2 and press A again, then click anywhere to proceed with the operation.
You can navigate the scene during transformation operations by pressing the Alt key in addition to the regular navigation mouse buttons.

I found the solution:

Move the cursor by holding Ctrl which then will snap the cursor to e.g. the corner of the cube or other selectable points
Set Transform Pivot Point to 3D Cursor
Select move
In the transform tool you can enter the coordinates to move to

This did the trick!
